# About non directional graphs with adjacency matrix representation

Tags: c, graph, bit-manipulation

I want to create a matrix representation for a graph algorithm using the least memory possible.

So I decided to try using a bit representation of the values of the matrix, but I also know that doing this by C is (AFAIK) impossible, because a bit is not addressable.

Then I read a post here suggesting to use a struct that can help me do so by using, e.g., an int (4 bytes, so 32-bit) and, with some magic and bitshifts, use it as an "array" of bits.

Got that, but I can't really realize how exactly I could do this. I got confused...

I'm thinking about using a structure to store a int/void pointer to n bytes corresponding to the least number of bytes to the 'n' number of bits allocated and the 'k' number of bits in that representation, something such as that.

So I thought you could help me realize what's the best approach for this kind of solution.

Note: Why I'm so confused? I'm still graduating in Computer Science and I just started to study graphs. Also just finished a laboratory project on that (implemented it as a matrix but used some mathemagic to alloc only half of the matrix and represented it as symectrical), but I'm trying to extend the matter. Also because I got extremely curious :)

Thanks all.

P.S.: almost forgot, I'm programming this in C, but I can understand C++, .Net languages and Java very well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of tricky bits here:  working on individual bits within a large array; and simulating a 2-dimensional array with a 1-dimensional one.  It's best to solve these separately at first.

Start with some helper functions that let you work on individual bits.  Something like:

```
typedef unsigned int BYTE;  /* Int type to use for data. */
#define BYTE_SIZE (sizeof(BYTE)*8)   /* How many bits in each one. */

void set_bit(BYTE *data, int pos, int value)
{
    int index = pos / BYTE_SIZE;   /* Which byte to adjust. */
    int offset = pos % BYTE_SIZE;  /* Which bit within it. */
    /* 1 << offset turns into the place value for the bit at offset. */
    /* x | 1 << offset sets the bit there (an OR operation);
       ~(1 << offset) gets something with all bits except that bit set, and
       x & ~(1 << offset) clears the bit with an AND operation on x. */
    if (value)
        data[index] = data[index] | (1 << offset);
    else
        data[index] = data[index] & ~(1 << offset);
}

int test_bit(int *data
{
    int index = pos / BYTE_SIZE;
    int offset = pos % BYTE_SIZE;
    /* An AND operation to see if the bit is set, then compare against 0
       so that 1 or 0 is returned instead of the place value. */
    return (data[index] & (1 << offset)) != 0;
}
```

You then move up a level with a structure to hold the array of bytes, and some data about the dimensions.  A 2-dimensional array can be simulated with a 1-d one, by translating a an operation on bit `(x,y)` to one on bit `y*width+x`.

```
struct BITMATRIX
{
    BYTE *data;
    int width;
    int height;
}

void set_bit_matrix(struct BITMATRIX *bm, int x, int y, int value)
{
    int pos = y * bm->width + x;
    set_bit(bm->data, pos, value);
}

/* Etc. */
```

Comment: Both answers do the job (already tested!), but this one actually gives me some of the algorithms I was trying to find. Thanks, Edmund :)

Comment: this answer deserves a lot of upvotes... Strictly speaking, your answer was great!!!

Comment: https://github.com/Abhishekghosh1998/SO/blob/master/bit_matrix.c my implementation based on the concept stated by @Edmund

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment on bit structs in C - take a look here:

- http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh(VS.80).aspx

These should be good pointers on how you should use bit structs.

Comment: Interesting! Didn't know that operator ':', so I don't need to be a bit-wizard then, haha. But, Unfortunatelly, as described in C99 Standards: "The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier." So bit-fields are one possible answer, but I can't make arrays or matrixes from them. By the way, loved to know I can work with bits that way, Thanks! :D

Comment: Glad it's useful. Rusty on C, so not saying it's not true, but not sure I follow the restriction from what you said. The above is just a restriction on `&` operator (i.e. you cannot do `a.b & c`, where `a.b` is a bit-field), but I don't think this says you cannot make an array of `a`.

Comment: You can, but of the struct, not the type. Yet it suffices. What I was trying to show on that restriction is that you cannot extract an address from one bit. The & operator acts giving you an address, and it says you can't use it on bit-fields. So bit-fields cannot be directly declared as arrays. It's almost a corollary =)

Comment: That's true, but I suppose it's going to allow you to make a helper function rather easy. If your struct is byte-oriented, then you need a get/set function part that just divides the address by 8 and then a simple switch to get/set the appropriate bit. Of course, your appetites might be greater :)

Comment: You are welcome - hope it's going to work out well one way or another.